# Use of article without (pro)noun: "Both of these terms matter, but the fall in lattice enthalpy is the more important"

Tags: articles, elision

From [Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group7/halideions.html#top):

> Both of these terms matter, but the fall in lattice enthalpy **is the more important**. This falls because the ions are getting bigger.

Shouldn't it be either "is the more important one/of the two" or simply "is more important"?

This use of the definite article without any noun or pronoun seems strange.

Comment: No. We can say "the more important of the two [aforementioned things]" but we don't need to add "of the two". The antecedent pair is understood. All forms occur often enough. Your choice.  X is more important. X is the more important. X is the more important of the two.

Comment: @TRomano You should write an answer.

Comment: @TRomano - I concur with User3169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternatives you provide may be more common, but the text's use of *is the more important* is also correct.

It can be seen as an ellison of the word *term*.

Answer (score 1):

Having the phrase *both of these terms*, we understand that there are two terms compared.*The more important* is a comparative used instead of a superlative.You use a superlative without a noun (That boy is the tallest. Or that boy is the taller).